# How to build a single binary in Gin with the History mode Vue

Tags: go

Just as Gin describe [here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1048)

```golang
r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("/src", false)))
r.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context){
    c.File("/src/index.html")
})
```

But I don't know how to inline the src folder into the binary file.

How should I proceed, or is there a case project I can refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is in `github.com/gin-contrib/static/_example/bindata`.

```golang
package main

import (
    assetfs "github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs"
    "github.com/fidelyiu/yiu-note/core/asset"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/static"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type binaryFileSystem struct {
    fs http.FileSystem
}

func (b *binaryFileSystem) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    return b.fs.Open(name)
}

func (b *binaryFileSystem) Exists(prefix string, filepath string) bool {

    if p := strings.TrimPrefix(filepath, prefix); len(p) < len(filepath) {
        if _, err := b.fs.Open(p); err != nil {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func BinaryFileSystem(root string) *binaryFileSystem {
    fs := &assetfs.AssetFS{
        Asset:     asset.Asset,
        AssetDir:  asset.AssetDir,
        AssetInfo: asset.AssetInfo,
        Prefix:    root,
    }
    return &binaryFileSystem{
        fs,
    }
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    // go-bindata -o=core/asset/asset.go -pkg=asset dist/...
    r.Use(static.Serve("/", BinaryFileSystem("dist")))
    r.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.File("./dist/index.html")
    })
    _ = r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Comment: cant we use the latest feature to embed resources like in https://github.com/gin-contrib/static/issues/19 ?  If i am correct the code does not use it, right ?